# php can't get the text from a text area

Tags: php, html

I can't figure out why this doesnt get the value of the textarea. I've been to loads of stackoverflow posts and I can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried getting values from textfields, from dropdown lists etc and they all work I just can't get the textarea to work. I've using _GET instead, still didnt work. 
This is the message I get if I don't use the isset function: Notice: Undefined index: descri.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
 <form role="form" action="saveform.php" method="post" name="eventform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="descri">Description</label>
      <textarea name="descri" form="eventform" style="resize:none"></textarea>
     </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addform">add</button>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['descri']))
    {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['descri']);
    } else {
      echo "DOESNTWORK";
}
?>
```

Comment: why you need  form="eventform"  in textarea?

Comment: I added it when I was searching through what was messing up and read on some post I needed to add that.. when I did something happened though it didnt work. So I guess Im back where I started. I think it's my Jquery script to check the length of the textarea that's messing it up somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove form attribute from textarea:

```
<textarea name="descri" form="eventform" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Comment: hmm ok, that actually work and helped me out what was causing the issue in my real code. Though I dont know what exacty and how. I have a jQuery script checking so the value doesnt go over 140 characters and that script is for some reason or other messing up so it passes an empty field to the PHP script I think. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Remove form attribute from `textarea` that is located inside the form:

```
<form role="form" action="saveform.php" method="post" name="eventform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="descri">Description</label>
      <textarea name="descri" style="resize:none"></textarea>
     </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addform">add</button>
</form>
```

You have to use it only when your textarea is outside the form (remember form should have `id` not just `name`:

```
<form role="form" action="saveform.php" method="post" id="eventform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="descri">Description</label>
     </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addform">add</button>
</form>
<textarea name="descri" form="eventform" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `form="eventform"` attribute from your `<textarea>` element. You do not need to set it as your `<form>` will post your data.

```
<form role="form" action="saveform.php" method="post" name="eventform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="descri">Description</label>
      <textarea name="descri" style="resize:none"></textarea>
     </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="addform">add</button>
</form>
```